# How to update the ng-model when using ng-options in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant make my model to be updated when I select an option.

Here is my view:

```
<select data-ng-model="period" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in periodOptions"></select>
```

And in my controller.js I have the following :

```
$scope.periodOptions = [
            { text: "This week", value: 'week' },
            { text:"This month", value: 'month '},
            { text:"This year",  value: 'year' }, 
            { text:"All times",  value: 'all-time '}
        ];

$scope.Search = function () {

            return $http({
                url: '/api/get',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    period: $scope.period
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, function(reason) {
                alert(reason);
            });
        };
```

The $scope.period does not take the value of the option that is chosen from the User. I spent many hours on this and can't figure it out why is this happening.

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/5IHYM086JgMzlPdFfACo?p=preview

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11190/

Comment: Can u use  params: {
                    'period': $scope.period
                }

Comment: when I console.log($scope.period) I get undefined. I see it gets the value on the plnkr.
But there might be a prb in the function part. Why $scope.period is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is a note in [angularjs documentation for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

  - "Note: ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects. See an example in this jsfiddle. "
- [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/) of same solution as yours.

Below is a solution which should work (Notice a minor change to your existing code use `ng-options="item as item.text ...` instead of `ng-options="item.value as item.text`). Hope this helps!

```js
var myCtrl = function($scope){
  
  $scope.periodOptions = [
            { text: "This week", value: 'week' },
            { text:"This month", value: 'month '},
            { text:"This year",  value: 'year' }, 
            { text:"All times",  value: 'all-time '}
        ];
  
$scope.Search = function () {
alert('will call api with period: '+$scope.period.text);
  /*
            return $http({
                url: '/api/get',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    period: $scope.period
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, function(reason) {
                alert(reason);
            });
            */
        };
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select data-ng-model="period" ng-options="item as item.text for item in periodOptions" ng-change="updatePeriod()"></select>
  <div>{{period}} </div>
  <button ng-click='Search()' >Search</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok I understand now and I changed the call to this :
  $scope.Search = function () {
                 return $http({
                url: '/api/ranks/get',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    period: $scope.period.value
                }
            }).then(function(response) {

            }, function(reason) {
                alert(reason);
            });
        };

But still $scope.period is undefined ?!

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to change that section. Please read my note above. Update your select's *ng-options*. Use `ng-options="item as item.text for item in periodOptions" `.  If you can post some more code of what you're trying to achieve then we probably have more idea.  Please use the code snippet above and let me know.  Update your *`ng-options`*

Comment: The approach you write it works . But my problem was that I had a nested scope. So I created another scope and put period on it, with the rest of filtering options and now it works.
I will accept your answer because it worked on plnkr and I had other things in my code to be fixed

Answer (score 8):

In my case `ng-model` was not updating because my `select` is inside an element with `ng-if`.

```xml
<div class="editor-panel" ng-if="editorEnabled">
    ...
    <select ng-options="item as item.description for item in items" ng-model="selectedItem"/>
    ...
</div>
```

`ng-if` creates another scope and `ng-model` refers to a variable in this child scope rather than the intended variable.

To fix the issue I changed `ng-model="selectedItem"` value to `ng-model="$parent.selectedItem`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select data-ng-model="period" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in periodOptions"></select>
    <span>period value=, {{period}}!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for select and `ngOptions` is correct. However I assume that you want `$scope.Search` function to be called on every option change. In this case you need to set up `ngChange` handler:

```
<select ng-model="period" 
        ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in periodOptions"
        ng-change="Search()">
</select>
```

Comment: I actually have a search button, but when I press it. It reaches
          params: { period: $scope.period.value } }). 
but it says $scope.period is undefined

Comment: Sounds like you have nested scope. Is the `ngInclude` or `ngIf` directives? If so setting initial value in topmost scope should help. In your controller add this `$scope.period = ''`.

Comment: Yes I had a nested scope . I fix it